# Using where with Merge Statement in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, merge, where-clause

I am trying to use Merge statement which updates if a condition is true else inserts.

Ex:

```
Merge INTO user_info T USING
        Dual
        ON (T.f_emp_id = in_emp_id)
        WHEN matched AND T.f_status NOT IN (3,4)

        THEN

        UPDATE..

        WHEN NOT matched THEN
        INSERT ..
```

I am getting exception that AND is an invalid keyword. How and where in the code to use the condition T.f_status NOT IN (3,4) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use below query, `WHERE` clause should be defined in the end
while using `MERGE` statement

```
 Merge INTO user_info T USING
    Dual
    ON (T.f_emp_id = in_emp_id)
    WHEN matched

    THEN

    UPDATE..

    WHEN NOT matched THEN
    INSERT ..

WHERE T.f_status NOT IN (3,4);
```